# Access array in a void method (c++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a print() method with the following header:

```
   void 2DArray::print() const
    {

    }
```

I call the method in another .cpp with array1.print(), but I don't know how to reference array1 of 2DArray type in the method because it is void. I need to access it's individual elements and print them. I am currently trying this:

```
cout << 2DArray[0][0];
```

The 2DArray type is defined in the header.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The posted code doesn't explain what you are trying to accomplish and where you are having a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. Please take another look.

Comment: An object knows about its own [data members](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).  When calling a member function, you have access to these data members, so there is no need to pass them as arguments.  I suggest a basic object-oriented tutorial if any of this seems surprising.

Comment: I think I understand it, but I don't know what specifically to use to call that. In java it was "this", I don't know if that exists in c++

Comment: You don't need any tricks to use class fields in a method of this class. Like this: `class A {public: int a; void print() {std::cout << a;}};`

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to guess what you want to accomplish.
If you have a 2DArray object, say o, in order to call print, you write

```
o.print();
```

If you have a pointer to a 2DArray object, then it is

```
p->print();
```

If you are inside a function of the 2DArray class, then it is

```
print();
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I have edited the question. I am trying to implement the print() method, I have array1.print(); called in another file.

Comment: You do not need to use "this", it is implicit. If "a" is a member of 2DArray, use "a" in the print function. It is equivalent to this->a. The void is the type returned by print. Nothing to do with the 2DArray itself.